# Latex different appendix section label

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning, appendix, hungarian

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[margin=1.5cm, noheadfoot]{geometry}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[magyar]{babel}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}


\begin{document}

\counterwithout{figure}{chapter}

\tableofcontents\vfill

\chapter{First}
\section{First section}
\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \includegraphics{example-image}
    \caption{Caption}
    \label{fig:ex}
\end{figure}

\clearpage
\pagenumbering{roman}
\renewcommand\thefigure{F.\arabic{figure}}    
\setcounter{figure}{0}
\appendix
\chapter*{Függelék}
\refstepcounter{chapter}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Függelék}
\section{First section in Ap}
\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \includegraphics{example-image}
    \caption{Caption}
    \label{fig:ap-ex}
\end{figure}
\section{Second section in Ap}


\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

As you can see in the Appendix (Függelék means Appendix in my native laguage), my Appendix section label is `A.1.` and `A.2.`, how could I change letter `A` to letter `F`? So appendix section label should be `F.1.` and `F.2.`

The label should change in the `toc` as well.

I only what one Appendix chapter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest you insert the instruction

```
\renewcommand\thesection{F.\arabic{section}}
```

immediately before the first `\section` directive following the `\appendix` directive.

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[margin=1.5cm, noheadfoot]{geometry}

%%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %  that's the default nowadays
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[magyar]{babel}

\usepackage{graphicx}
%%\usepackage{float}

\counterwithout{figure}{chapter}


\begin{document}

\tableofcontents%\vfill % \vfill isn't needed

\listoffigures

\chapter{First chapter}
\section{First section in chapter 1}

\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \includegraphics{example-image}
    \caption{Caption}
    \label{fig:ex}
\end{figure}

\clearpage
\pagenumbering{roman}
\renewcommand\thefigure{F.\arabic{figure}}    
\setcounter{figure}{0}
\appendix
\chapter*{Függelék}
\refstepcounter{chapter}

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Függelék}
\renewcommand\thesection{F.\arabic{section}} % <-- new

\section{First section in Appendix}

\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \includegraphics{example-image}
    \caption{Caption text}
    \label{fig:ap-ex}
\end{figure}

\section{Second section in Apppendix}

\end{document}
```